# Getting thumbnails from a JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need this script to be able to pull out thumbnails from the Google API JSON, for some reason, it doesn't seem to be working. Attached a jsfiddle as wel.l

```
        <div id="book-shelf">

        </div>
                    $(function() {
    var i=0;
    var googleApi = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=edgar+allan+poe";
    var googleData;
    $.getJSON(googleApi, function(json) {
        googleData = json;

        setData()
    });

    function setData(){
        var j = googleData.length > (i + 9)  ? (i + 9) : googleData.length;
        for (; i < j; i++) {
            var googleThumb = googleData[i].thumbnail;
            var img = $('<img style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" src="' + googleThumb + '"/>')
            $('#book-shelf').append(img);
        }
    }       

    $('#load').click(function() {
        setData();
    }); 
});



        https://jsfiddle.net/mo7skwrj/
```

Comment: Define *"doesn't seem to be working"*. What debugging have you done? What errors are in the developer console?

Comment: @squint I am not getting any errors. The code should grab the thumbnails from the JSON and place them as images inside the #book-shelf. + Edited the code in the question.

Comment: Set `?` as the callback name so that jQuery will handle the JSONP response automatically *(that is if you didn't create your own `handleResponses` function)*... `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=edgar+allan+poe&callback=?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the API URL, you left `callback=handleResponses`, but that would only be applicable if you had such a function declared in your code. With this parameter, you would receive JSONP (a JS call to that function), not JSON.

You could just remove that to get JSON (but it might fail in legacy browsers that don't support [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)), or, as [@squint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1106925/squint) suggests, replace `callback=handleResponses` with `callback=?` in the API URL, to let jQuery handle the callback.

You also need to change this:

`googleData[i].thumbnail`

into this:

`googleData[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail`

[**Fixed JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/n9otvn51/)

Comment: @JohnDotHR: Be aware that this will fail in legacy browsers that don't support CORS. That's why JSONP exists.

Comment: @squint Thanks for the info. I changed my answer to include that.

Comment: Your original answer was fine too if the OP doesn't need that legacy support. Maybe include both points so that people can know both solutions. Probably good to note that the server needs to allow for such cross-domain transfers for CORS to work. Seems that this API does allow it.